# How to add column in catalog_product_flat table in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have tried this code for sales_flat_quote_item table?

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('sales/quote_item'), 'customized_product_solitaire', 'int(1) NOT NULL');
$installer->getConnection()
          ->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('sales/order_item'), 'customized_product_solitaire', 'int(1) NOT NULL');
```

Comment: are u want to add columns which table `sales_flat_quote_item`  or `catalog_product_flat`?

Comment: I want to add column in catalog_product_flat table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead :

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote_item'), 'customized_product_solitaire', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'nullable' => false,
            'length'    => 1
        ));
$installer->getConnection()
          ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order_item'), 'customized_product_solitaire', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'nullable' => false,
            'length'    => 1
        ));
```

Comment: I want to add column in catalog_product_flat table

Comment: Then you need to change table name, use `$installer->getTable('catalog/product_flat')`